# How do I use GroundControl in 11.10?

Tags: bazaar

When I installed Bazaar Explorer on a fresh system the other day, I came across this Ground Control. I had a look at its web page on http://ground-control.org/ and it looked seriously awesome, so I installed it from Ubuntus repositories. However, I can't find any way of starting it.

apt-file shows that it should provide a file named /usr/share/applications/groundcontrol.desktop, but there's no such file. Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

In my system, the .desktop is located here: `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/groundcontrol:groundcontrol.desktop`. To find it on your system, use

```
sudo updatedb
locate groundcontrol | grep .desktop
```

To start the program, hit `Alt+F2` and then write `lp-groundcontrol`

Comment: It still doesn't work though. I were actually able to login and such, but it doesn't appear in Nautilus. :/

Comment: I tried the development version, and it also doesn't works (i can just login).